# Finding the minimum distance $d=d(C)$ of $C$

Tags: coding-theory

The parity check matrix of a generator matrix $G$ is given as 
$$H=\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array} \right]$$

I am trying to find $d=d(C)$.Where $C$ is a linear $[n,K] $ code.

The solutions say in $H$ every two columns are different but some $3$ are dependant for example $C_1+ C_6+C_7=0$.

How does $C_1+ C_6+C_7=0$?

In general how do you find $d(C)$?

Comment: Is the code meant to be binary? You see that $C_1+C_6+C_7=0$ by finding the sum of columns 1,6 and 7 (modulo 2).

Comment: And, no general low-complexity method for finding the minimum distance of a code is known. Even weaker problems are known to reside in one of those nasty categories within the NP-hierarchy. You are expected to use ad hoc methods (such as spotting sets of linearly dependent columns of the parity check matrix).

Answer (score 2):

It holds that 
$$d(C)=\min \{ d \in \mathbb{N} | \text{ there are } d \text{ linearly dependent columns of H} \}$$

So firstly you check if you have a column only with  $0$s. If not then all the $\{ C_i \}$ are linearly independent. Then $d \neq 1$.

After that you check if there is an $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $C_i= \alpha C_j$ for some $i,j$ such that $i \neq j$ and $1 \leq i,j \leq 7$. If not then $d \neq 2$.

Then you check if there are $\alpha, \beta \neq 0$ such that $\alpha C_i+ \beta C_j=C_k$ for any $1 \leq k \leq 7, i, j \neq k, 1 \leq i,j \leq 7$.

If so, then $d=3$. Otherwise you continue in the same way by checking if there are non-zero $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ such that $C_k=\alpha C_1+ \beta C_2+ \gamma C_3$. If so, then $d$ will be equal to $4$.

Otherwise, you continue checking the same thing for four columns.

Comment: Sorry about forgetting to upvote this back then. Mistake corrected now :-)